# How to print preview a selection?

Tags: front-end

When printing (file->print...) there's the possibility of printing just the current selection. This is useful for printing just a couple of cells, or some chapters.

The file menu also has Print Preview, but with no options.

Is there a way of making a print preview of a selection?

Comment: For what it's worth you can always print to PDF, using either OS tools if provided or free utilities.

Comment: What OS are you using? On OS X, _Mathematica_ (ver. 8) has no File > Print Preview item. This is probably because the two menu items for printing, Print... and Print Selection ..., both bring up a system Print dialog that offers a Preview button.

Comment: Use Szabolcs' uploader, but don't upload :D

Comment: @Mr.Wizard that's what I generally do, but to test out printing options/stylesheets it is faster to use the print preview (gain that is quickly lost if it doesn’t work on a selection). To be honest, I never understood what was the ultimate purpose of the print preview functionality (it seems unfinished). I always thought it appeared as a general thought that WRI had on improving word processing functionalities (...the paper support is not dead...). Now after m_goldberg comment, it looks more like having similar functionality on different OS.

Comment: @m_goldberg Windows

Comment: You may be able to get at least some useful information by setting **Format** > **Screen Environment** to **Printout**.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard actually, I never liked that quality of the information I gained with that...

Comment: @rm-rf does it support headers and footers?

Comment: @P.Fonseca No, just the selection. I wasn't really sure what you meant by print preview of a selection and assumed you meant just a rasterized version of the selection for previewing...